# determinar si una cadena de caracteres está incluida en otra

Tags: python, string

*Buenas noches, estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y un ejercicio me pide determinar si una cadena esta dentro de otra sin importar el orden de los caracteres y teniendo en cuenta las repeticiones, este es el código que llevo. En este caso me arroja que la cadena no esta incluida ya que pepito tiene dos p mientras que la otra cadena solo una, el problema radica en que si quito una p, a la palabra pepito, me sigue mostrando que sigue sin estar incluida. He intentado hacer lo mismo con find pero aun no lo logro. Muchas gracias*

```
text_1='pepito'
text_2='un pedazo de tierra' 
if text_1.count('pepito',0,6) == text_2.count('un pedazo de tierra',0,18):
  print('La cadena esta incluida')
else:
  print('La cadena no esta incluida')
```

Comment: En resumen, quieres saber si text_1 se encuentra dentro de text_2? o quieres saber si cada caracter de text_1 se encuentra en text_2?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno para saber si la cadena esta en otra utilizamos la palabra clave `in` para determinar si algo se encuentro dentro de otra cosa.

Luego para validar validar no se repita la letra, simplemente la quitamos, esto con ayuda del método `replace()`.

Por último creamos una variable de *"control"* para saber si el texto el resultado final, esta variable será una booleana.
Además si tan solo una letra no se encuentra en la otra cadena, rompemos el ciclo y decimos que no coincide.

```py
for l in text_1:
  if l in text_2:
    coincidencia = True
    text_2 = text_2.replace(l,"")
    print(text_2)
    continue
  else:
    print("la cadena no está incluida")
    coincidencia = False 
    break
if coincidencia:
  print("la cadena si esta")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás poniendo en `text_2.count('un pedazo de tierra', 0, 18)` el `18`.

si haces `print('un pedazo de tierra'[0:18])` varás que eso te devuelve `un pedazo de tierr` por lo que:

```
print(text_2.count('un pedazo de tierra', 0, 18))
```

Te devolverá siempre 0.

Puedes omitir tanto el `0,6` y el `0,8` y dejarlo así:

```
if text_1.count('pepito') == text_2.count('un pedazo de tierra'):
```

Eso si, lo que estás comprobando no es que las cadenas estén incluidas, lo que estás comprobando es que en ambos caso pase lo mismo. Es decir si:

- `pepito` está 1 vez en `texto_1` y `un pedazo de tierra` está 1 vez
  en `texto_2` Devolverá `La cadena esta incluida`.
- `pepito` está 0 veces en `texto_1` y `un pedazo de tierra` está 0 veces
  en `texto_2` Devolverá `La cadena esta incluida`.
- `pepito` está 0 veces en `texto_1` y `un pedazo de tierra` está 1 vez
  en `texto_2` Devolverá `La cadena no esta incluida`.
- `pepito` está 1 vez en `texto_1` y `un pedazo de tierra` está 2 veces
  en `texto_2` Devolverá `La cadena no esta incluida`.

Creo que se entiende, y si no ejecuta este código y verás que te dice que la cadena está incluida porque ambos aparecen 0 veces:

```
text_1='pepito'
text_2='un pedazo de tierra' 
if text_1.count('esto no está') == text_2.count('esto no está'):
    print('La cadena esta incluida')
else:
    print('La cadena no esta incluida')
```

**Cómo buscar la cadena sin importar el orden**

Puedes buscar la cadena con la clase [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) del módulo `collections`, que te devuelve un diccionario con la cantidad de veces que aparece cada caracter, es decir:

from collections import Counter

```
text_1='pepito'
c1 = Counter(text_1)

print(c1)
```

Devuelve `Counter({'p': 2, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 't': 1, 'o': 1})`

Con lo que haciendolo para `text_1` y `text_2` puedes mirar que `text_1` tenga menos veces cada caracter.

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter('epito')
c2 = Counter('un pedazo de tierra')

print(all([c1[c] <= c2[c] for c in c1]))
```

Con `[c1[c] <= c2[c] for c in c1]` te devuelve `True` o `False` dependiendo si cada caracter de `c1` está menos o igual veces en `c2`, lo que podría por ejemplo ser una lista tal que así `[False, True, True, False, True, True]`. Al ponerle `all()` delante obligamos a que devuelva `True` si todos cumplen, y `False` si hay al menos uno que no.

Verás que ahora con `pepito` no cumple, pero con `epito` si.